arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc compiles for armv7 and armv8 although configured for armv7?
I have downloaded version 13.2 of the official ARM linux gnueabihf toolchain from ARM.
I checked the configuration command line:
$ /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-g
nueabihf-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/13.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --prefix= --with-sysroot=/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-build-sysroot=/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/build-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/install//arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-bugurl=https://bugs.linaro.org/ --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-shared --disable-libssp --disable-libmudflap --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/build-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-mpfr=/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/build-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-mpc=/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/build-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-isl=/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/build-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=neon --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --with-arch=armv7-a --with-pkgversion='Arm GNU Toolchain 13.2.rel1 (Build arm-13.7)'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.2.1 20231009 (Arm GNU Toolchain 13.2.rel1 (Build arm-13.7))

It shows --with-arch=armv7-a and I was under the impression that this matters.
But when I compile a test binary for armv8, it seems to produce the correct tag:
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -march=armv7-a  -shared -fPIC -o arm_raw_v7.so test.c
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -march=armv8-a  -shared -fPIC -o arm_raw_v8.so test.c
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf -A arm_raw_v?.so | grep Tag_CPU_arch:
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch: v8

When I do the same test with the RPi3+ toolchain from here, the compiler would accept -march=armv7-a but the resulting binary would still print tag v8.
The configuration options for the RPi toolchain:
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../configure --prefix= --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-sysroot=/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-arch=armv8-a --with-fpu=neon-fp-armv8 --with-float=hard --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)

Could somebody explain why the official ARM toolchain produces binaries for both ISA although configured for armv7a?

these are not "official" arm toolchains, they are open source builds that they share with the public.

The configuration is a default.  Ie, you don't send any flags, then what happens?  arm7a?  It may also set a minimum library.  So the 'libc' will be compiled to work with armv7a.  armv8 is backwards compatible with armv7a, so the compiler can still produce these.  Also, you are NOT making 64bit armv8, but 32bit ISA.
